# Footer help please - Issues with text alignment

Tags: footer, tumblr

I'm having issues with my footer. It's the appropriate width and length but I can't get the text to move.

I've tried toggling with the numbers, using both negative and positive numbers with no luck. I'm using a theme created by another tumblr user, with permission to edit it to my liking, but she won't help me edit it, which is how I got here.

I'd like the text on the left side to be 20px from the left, and the text on the right to be 20px from the right. Both sets of text should be 15px from the top. (These are just guesses- once this problems solved, I'll probably toggle a bit more.)

Here's a link to the coding: http://pastebin.com/c0RdkC4W

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I think it is a bit much to expect someone to go through your entire tumblr code. A better approach would be to send a link to the live tumblr, and tell us the elements you wish to pad, it would then be possible to write a little css which would go in the head of the document and style the elements for you.

Comment: To add to @lharby comment please add an example link, so we don't have to create one ourselves. You have more chance of an answer if we can quickly look at an example.

Comment: Here you go: http://kuygaerkuy.tumblr.com/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you have some css being applied to the footer (I assume you are talking about the main site footer rather than the footer for each post.

You need to find the css for the #footer

And apply the following css:

```
 #footer {
    padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
    height: 130px;
 }
```

That is in addition to the properties already applied to that element. It's on line 231 of the full block of html you posted.

I am afraid setting the height on the footer is a hack, you would have to adjust this if you add or remove navigation items. A better solution is to use clearfix.

You also have some inline styles hard coded into the html, this is often frowned upon as it is easier to control the css using classes, id's and element selectors. But sometimes these inline styles get written to the template via the tumblr options.

See how you get on and give us a shout if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you! I have a couple of questions. Before adding the css you gave me there was a larger space between the bottom of the page and the div. How can I get that back? Also, the width of the div was 790px prior, and somehow it shrunk? How can I change that back? (http://i.imgur.com/Xr3H9it.png)

Comment: Okay, so I made the div wider by adding `width:95%;` to the footer css but I still can't manage to get the space between the bottom of the page and the footer back to where it was. (30px maybe?)

Comment: I would actually remove the width parameter, and then the div will simply fill the full width of the parent container. Initially on the footer there was padding:100px (which applies padding of 100px to the top, right, bottom and left, hence reducing the width once you put in those new values. If you want a margin below the footer so there is a white border, apply this to the footer css
margin-bottom: 25px; I think this is what you mean.

Comment: There is already a margin set on the footer of margin:15px 0 0;
I would change it to margin:15px 0 30px 0; see how that looks.